# How to specialize templated method in templated class?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I'm finding C++ templates incredibly difficult to wrap my head around. Now I'm attempting to specialize a templated member function of a templated class:

```
template <bool COW>
class BaseReferencedObject {
public:
    BaseReferencedObject()                                 : refCount(0) {}
    BaseReferencedObject(const BaseReferencedObject<COW>&) : refCount(0) {}
    BaseReferencedObject<COW>& operator=(const BaseReferencedObject<COW>&) {return *this;}
    template <bool COW2> void increaseRefCount() const;
    void decreaseRefCount() const {refCount--;}
    int getRefCount() const {return refCount;}
private:
    mutable int refCount;
};

class BaseReferencedObject<false>;
class BaseReferencedObject<true >;

template<> void BaseReferencedObject<false>::increaseRefCount<false>() const {refCount++;}
template<> void BaseReferencedObject<true >::increaseRefCount<true >() const {refCount++;}

typedef BaseReferencedObject<false> ReferencedObject;
typedef BaseReferencedObject<true > SharedData      ;
```

*However, when I try to compile this code, I get*

```
SharedPtr.hh:31:62: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
 template<> void BaseReferencedObject<false>::increaseRefCount<false>() const {refCount++;}
                                                              ^
```

*What does this mean, and how should I go ahead doing this?* I have tried to find the solution by googling, but I haven't been able to find anything that works.

By the way, can someone recommend any good resource for better understanding how C++ templates work at their core?

---

Brief about what I'm trying to do here: I also have a second class `template <bool COW> class BaseSharedPointer` which is a class of shared pointers referencing objects that have inherited from either `ReferencedObject` or from `SharedData`. The idea is that only shared pointers that make use of [copy-on-write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) (COW) should be able to reference objects that are supposed to be copied on write (true–true combination), and only shared pointers that don't use of COW should be able to reference objects that are not supposed to be copied on write (false–false combination). The other two combinations (true–false, false–true) shouldn't be allowed since mixing smart pointers that make use of COW and smart pointers that don't is deemed to be a bad idea. Hence, I'm trying to make those combinations impossible by only instantiating the specializations of the `increaseRefCount` method for the combinations that are allowed, and leaving it uninstantiated for the other two specializations to raise a compilation error if some code try to use any of them.

Comment: The specialization should just be: `template<> void BaseReferencedObject<false>::increaseRefCount() ...`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Wouldn't that specialize only the class? I want to specialize the class–method combination as both the class and the method are templated.

Comment: Sorry I've been overlooking its a templated function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add another `template<>` to specialize the member functions

```
template<> template<> void BaseReferencedObject<false>::increaseRefCount<false>() const {refCount++;}
template<> template<> void BaseReferencedObject<true >::increaseRefCount<true >() const {refCount++;}
```

Note that you can only specialize member functions for specializations of the surrounding class templates.

However, your code example has two other aspects that are not entirely correct. First, it's best to provide a default implementation for `increaseRefCount` (this can be done inside the class template definition). Second, your two lines

```
class BaseReferencedObject<false>;
class BaseReferencedObject<true >;
```

cause the somewhat cryptic compiler error that you mention in the comments. If you [**use clang instead of g++**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d068a25e8941eada) as compiler, you get a much clearer error for those lines:

> error: template specialization requires 'template<>'

as well as the error

> error: incomplete type 'BaseReferencedObject' named in nested name specifier

for the member function specialization. The reason is that you are not defining the class template specializations, but are simply forward declaring them. However, it's not necessary because you can specialize member functions without providing the full class template specializations.

Here's a fully working code example:

```
#include <iostream>

template <bool COW>
class BaseReferencedObject {
public:
    BaseReferencedObject()                                 : refCount(0) {}
    BaseReferencedObject(const BaseReferencedObject<COW>&) : refCount(0) {}
    BaseReferencedObject<COW>& operator=(const BaseReferencedObject<COW>&) {return *this;}
    template <bool COW2> void increaseRefCount() const { std::cout << "DEFAULT\n"; refCount++; }
    void decreaseRefCount() const {refCount--;}
    int getRefCount() const {return refCount;}
private:
    mutable int refCount;
};

template<> template<> void BaseReferencedObject<false>::increaseRefCount<false>() const { std::cout << "FALSE\n"; refCount++;}
template<> template<> void BaseReferencedObject<true >::increaseRefCount<true >() const { std::cout << "TRUE \n"; refCount++;}

typedef BaseReferencedObject<false> ReferencedObject;
typedef BaseReferencedObject<true > SharedData      ;

int main()
{
    BaseReferencedObject<false> b0;
    BaseReferencedObject<true > b1;

    b0.increaseRefCount<false>();
    b0.increaseRefCount<true>();
    b1.increaseRefCount<true >();
    b1.increaseRefCount<false>();
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c5248b26de13e028).

**Update**: if you don't want a default implementation, you can explicitly delete the other combinations

```
template<> template<> void BaseReferencedObject<false>::increaseRefCount<true>() const = delete;
template<> template<> void BaseReferencedObject<true >::increaseRefCount<false >() const = delete;
```

This gives a compiler error instead of a linker error for when you only left out the default implementation.

Comment: This doesn't work; then I get `SharedPtr.hh:31:28: error: too many template-parameter-lists`, `template<> template<> void BaseReferencedObject<false>::increaseRefCount<false>() const {refCount++;}` instead.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye that was because your code had some other subtle issues. I expanded the answer by fully explaining it and providing a working example that resolves all issues.

Comment: Now I got it working. Thanks! My two mistakes seem to have been that I used `template<>` instead of `template<> template<>` in the method specializations, and that I declared specializations of the class without defining them. But why is it best to provide a default implementation for `increaseRefCount`? I don't seem to need that, and I want the compiler to generate an error if any of the combinations false–true or true–false is called to prevent myself from accidentally adding that combination to my program, so I don't want a default implementation. Why do you think I should have one?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye if you know for sure that you don't need them, by all means drop the default impl, but it's best then to explicitly delete it. See updated answer.

Comment: Okay, I chose to do the latter. Thank you very much!